# sidebar menu triangle pointer appears after click

Tags: jquery, css

I've created a simple sidebar nav menu [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/N3awMbbLbwadH5XSlsNS?p=preview), as you can see - when clicking on the links - the rectangle/triangle remains.... 
Wonder how to fix it.... and why is it happening.

Here is how i got the pointer.

```
ul.faq_questions li.active:after, ul.faq_questions li:hover:after {
content: "";
position: absolute;
width: 10px;
height: 10px;
background:#5d3c95;
-webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
right: -5px;
top: 40%;
}
```

Comment: remove li.active::after from above code or change the active li background-color

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this following code

css

```
ul.faq_questions li.active
{
  background-color: #5d3c95;
  color:#fff;
}

ul.faq_questions li.active:after, ul.faq_questions li:hover:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background:#5d3c95;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    right: -5px;
  top: 40%;
}
```

hope this works..

or

remove

```
ul.faq_questions li.active:after
```

from present code